# How do I make this object-oriented?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo, object-oriented-database

Currently I have the code below which registers a user.

It doesn't check to see if the username currently exists or anything like that, that is something that I want to implement.

I've never known how to use php objects and forms together. Any help will be much appreciated.

`register.php`

The page checks to see if a user is already logged in, either way the form is still displayed and submits to itself. The database access details are stored in `config.php` as constants.

```
<?php
session_start();

include("includes/config.php");

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo "You are currently logged in as: " . $_SESSION['username'];
    echo "<br />";
    include("nav.php");
    echo "<hr />";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$odb = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_SERVER . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);





if (isset($_POST['firstName'])) {
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = md5(DB_SALT.$password);
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $date=date("Y-m-d");                
    $time=date("H:i:s");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblMembers (firstName, lastName, username, passwordHash, type, joinedDate, joinedTime, lastActiveDate, lastActiveTime) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName, :username, :passwordHash, :type, :joinedDate, :joinedTime, :lastActiveDate, :lastActiveTime);";
    $query = $odb->prepare($sql);
    $results = $query->execute(array(
        ":firstName" => $firstName,
        ":lastName" => $lastName,
        ":username" => $username,
        ":passwordHash" => $password,
        ":type" => $type,
        ":joinedDate" => $date,
        ":joinedTime" => $time,
        ":lastActiveDate" => $date,
        ":lastActiveTime" =>$time
        ));
}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
    Name: <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="Michael" /><br />
    Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" value="Norris" /><br />
    Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="mstnorris" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="password" /><br />
    Type: <input type="text" id="type" name="type" value="4" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I know how to write php objects using classes. This is what I had previously although I have been told that the methods I used are outdated. If anyone can shed any light on how to update it, it sure would help.

```
<?php

require_once("database.php");

class Member extends DatabaseObject {
    protected static $table_name = "tblMembers";
    var $firstName = "Mike"; // initiating the $firstName variable
    var $lastName = "Norris"; // initiating the $lastName variable
    var $username = "mstnorris"; // initiating the $username variable
    var $password = "password"; // initiating the $password variable
    var $reviews = "0"; // initiating the $reviews variable
    var $type = "4"; // initiating the $type variable

    function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $username, $password, $reviews, $type) {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->reviews = $reviews;
        $this->type = $type;
        //$this->insert($firstName, $lastName, $username, $password, $type);
    }

    function set_firstName($firstName) {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
    }

    function get_firstName() {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    function set_lastName($lastName) {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }

    function get_lastName() {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    function get_fullName() {
        if (isset($this->firstName) && isset($this->lastName)) {
            return $this->firstName . " " . $this->lastName;    
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    function set_username($username) {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    function get_username() {
        return $this->username;
    }

    function set_password($password) {
        $this->password = md5(DB_SALT.$password);
    }

    function get_password() {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public static function authenticate($username="", $password="") { 
        global $database;
        $username = $database->escape_value($username);
        $password = $database->escape_value($password);
        $passwordHash = md5(DB_SALT.$password);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblMembers ";
        $sql .= "WHERE username = '{$username}' ";
        $sql .= "AND passwordHash = '{$passwordHash}' ";
        $sql .= "LIMIT 1";

        $result_array = self::find_by_sql($sql);
        if (!empty($result_array)) {
            //echo "true";
            return array_shift($result_array); // Pulling first element from array
        } else {
            //echo "false";
            return false; // Ability to ask whether we return something
        }

    }

    public function insert($firstName, $lastName, $username, $password) {
        $database = new Database();
        $database->query("INSERT INTO tblMembers VALUES ('','{$firstName}','{$lastName}','{$username}','{$password}','4')");
    }

    // Common Database Methods

    private static function instantiate($record) {
        $object = new self;

        foreach ($record as $attribute=>$value) {
            if ($object->has_attribute($attribute)) {
                $object->$attribute = $value;
            }
        }
        return $object;
    }

    public static function find_all() {
        return self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM ".self::$table_name);
    }

    public static function find_by_id($id=0) {
        global $database;
        $result_array = self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM ".self::$table_name." WHERE userID={$id} LIMIT 1");
        if (!empty($result_array)) {
            return array_shift($result_array); // Pulling first element from array
        } else {
            return false; // Ability to ask whether we return something
        }
    }   

    public static function find_by_sql($sql="") {
        global $database;
        $result_set = $database->query($sql);
        $object_array = array();
        while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result_set)) {
            $object_array[] = self::instantiate($row);
        }
        return $object_array;
    }

    private function has_attribute($attribute) {
        $object_vars = get_object_vars($this);
        return array_key_exists($attribute, $object_vars);
    }
}

?>
```

Can the MVC approach be used with AJAX? Also, with that in mind, the AJAX code I have used before in other projects use $_GET, is there any problems with this as the data is never being sent to the address bar? If so, how do I use $_POST with AJAX?

Comment: Why do you need so many getters and setters?  Why won't __get or __set suffice?

Comment: Simply change the $database methods to something similar to the PDO methods you have in the first code snipet.

Comment: __get or __set will allow you to set the attributes value in your code like this: |1. instantiate| $var = new Object(); |2. __set| $var->attribute = $value |3. __get| $value = $var->attribute |..  I am assuming that your actually calling your functions like so: |1.| $var->set_lastName( $lastName ); | and getting the values like: |2.| $value = $var->get_lastName( ); |

Comment: Also, you don't need the var keyword.

Comment: @Rafael, how to I add Members from a form? Can you provide an example in the form of an answer?

Comment: Thanks @CharlesAddis, I have added another question regarding the use of AJAX

Comment: @Mike - That is kind of a separate question and I've just now seen it so I'll update my answer, but I think you should use the search function as PHP OOP is not easy, from the looks of it you don't have a basic understanding of how the php language works, what OOP is, how ajax works, why one would use OOP as opposed to procedural programming, what problems OOP aims to solve for programmers, etc.

Comment: @Mike You should really try to understand how to program before you potentially put an insecure script on the internet and somebody uses an sql injection to hack into your database (ie gets around your htmlentities() call).  Seriously read the PHP manual completely or read a book because if you don't know every tool that PHP has to offer you will probably not have a very efficient or secure solution to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Mike see my revised answer below

Answer (score 1):

Mike:

your set a getter and a setter like this:

```
class Spam
{
    public $attr;
    public $var;
    public $arg;

    /* __construct, __set, and __get 
      these are all special functions
      we know this from the double underscore */

    function __construct () 
    {
           // construction code
    }

    function __set ( $arg0, $arg1 )
    {    
           $this->$arg0 = $arg1;
    }

    function __get ( $arg )
    {
           return $this->$arg;
    }
}
```

and you would call it from your code as follows:

```
// this calls the __constructor function
$barney = new Spam();

// this calls the __set function
$barney->attr = "garnished with spam & eggs";

// this calls the __get function
$attrValue = $barney->attr;
```

This reduces the need to call a different method to set/get the values of your variable.  This will only work on public variables as private and protected variables cannot be accessed from outside of your class.

Also, it is a good idea to have separate views, models, and controllers.  Your controller is the script that the form submits to, your model is the class that is instantiated, and your view is where the user sends the information from.  This will make your code easier to understand, rather than having your controller and view together.

Are you restricted to PHP4 for some reason?  Or did you download some really old code and you're now trying to get it to work?

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[ UPDATE 2.27.2013 ]>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

***OOP PHP Programming in Conjunction with JavaScript AJAX technology***

*Model-View-Controller:*

> MVC is not specific to PHP.  MVC is a software design pattern that aims to solve a maintainability problem in code that combines separate
>   components of the code in ways that make the code less readable and
>   hard to maintain, which in the end is also a security risk. 
>   Model-View-Controller is typically implemented via frameworks.  In
>   regards to PHP there are frameworks available such as Zend,
>   CodeIgniter, CakePHP, etc.  There frameworks implement the model view
>   controller through the document tree, although you can create your own
>   PHP framework (which isn't a good idea given your new to the
>   language), its probably better to use one that has already been
>   around.  These frameworks may also enforce their own standards that result
>   in better code.
>
> [image: Model-View-Controller]
>
> To understand a maintainable MVC framework you should be familiar with coding a website > > entirely in PHP.  That means you should be using PHP classes [modules|models] to 
>   dynamically generate the HTML pages[the view] depending what the user has done[the 
>   **controller** file controls the model].
>
> You question is very vague and its hard to tell what your asking, however, I get the 
>   impression you're unable to figure out what MVC is and how to use it.  Suppose you've 
>   just created a layout for a website you will be developing.  Since it
>   isn't possible to predict the size of your user's screen, you're
>   layout was designed in the browser.  Your layout [or template if you
>   will] should be standard compliant HTML5 or XHTML.  It should not be
>   constructed with images.  Some people may disagree with me on this but
>   with the exception of your logo/header(though some use text for this
>   too), you should not have any  tags are part of your
>   template(this is before any content has been written, obviously you'll
>   probably want to use a lot of images in your content).  Your view at
>   this point should be HTML and CSS - any images that are a part of your
>   layout (ie patterns, backgrounds, anything layout specific) should be
>   in the CSS of your website.  This is kind of the same reason that we
>   use the MVC pattern - it separates what should be separate.
>
> You take your layout as the HTML and you write a PHP class[module]
>   that contains functions, for example we'll use
>   $view->showLeadboard();, $view->showAds(); $view->showFooter();
>   $view->setTitle("Title");, $view->setDescription("Description");... 
>   This assumes that you've instantiated your class.  Perhaps you don't
>   want to instantiate a class and you'd prefer to use static methods,
>   the choice is yours but you should understand what you're doing well
>   enough to have good reasons for doing it.
>
> Now that your view is held inside of a PHP module you can worry about
>   your content.  Chances are, if your website is dynamic, there will be
>   multiple pages and locations on those pages that contain dynamic
>   content from a database, or forms (we're still inside of the view)
>   that submit data to the controller.
>
> Suppose somebody is registering at your website.  The go to your
>   domain and a view is generated based on the request to
>   **www.site.com** and the view that is generated is the index page.  This person who has come to your page has decided to register for an
>   account with your service.  They click on the "register" hyperlink and
>   another view is generated that displays a form for them to create
>   their login credentials.  They fill the form out click submit.  The
>   information supplied in the form is submitted to a controller(we're
>   not talking about ajax or implementing an MVC design pattern for our
>   javascript code right now), we'll say that the view
>   **site.com/register** submits to the controller **site.com/engine/process.php**.  *Process.php* filters/sanitizes the user data from the form and instantiates the correct class(model,
>   we'll call this one *new* ***User***) that will then make a database
>   call through one of its methods, or maybe even through its
>   constructor(you should be aware of the magic methods available to you
>   in PHP) and this the result of this query mutates the view to be
>   slightly different depending on what the controller told the model and
>   what the model told the view.

I don't even know what I can say about your question regarding AJAX - given your position with PHP I'm going to guess that you're using JQuery for ajax calls.  If this is the case you do not need to implement a model-view-controller from your jquery files, you can just create a jquery script and then add a method to your view that calls that script and implements it.

**All in all if you are struggling to understand what a common pattern like MVC is and how to use it you should really go back to the basics.  I can't stress enough that the online tutorials aren't going to help you if you don't understand why the author used the solution that they used and chances are they're not explaining that to you because its sometime simple that you should be able to understand yourself provided you have a basic understanding of the php language, its syntax, and how to solve problems with it.  This all comes just from spending time with the language, learning how it works, and learning what it doesnt do well and what it does do well.**

Comment: The top code I believe to be the modern way of doing things (PDO), the bottom part is from a tutorial about 5 years ago, I appreciate it uses out of date methods but at the time they were write and I thought it would be a good place to start. How do I access private or protected variables then? Also, how is this handled when the data is coming from a form? This is the thing I am having most trouble with and I am sure it is the simplest.

Comment: What do you mean?  I think you're horribly confused about what Object Oriented programming is.  You would access form data the exact same way that you would if you were programming in a procedural syntax.  You just assign the data to your Class attributes rather than a variable.

Comment: I suggest you go to your local barnes & noble, pick up a PHP book and read the section on Object Oriented programming.  Your going to have a lot easier time learning PHP from up to date reading material than from old tutorials

Comment: I have found lots of resources online but none that are simple enough to follow. Once I get this working I am putting one together myself!

Comment: Putting a tutorial together yourself?  No offense, but from the looks of your code you don't really understand PHP at all.  I've only been programming in PHP since August but I have read a lot on PHP and have already built the back end of my website myself.  Only tutorials never helped me really, except for specific problems.  but not for understanding php

Comment: Yeah, What I am trying to achieve can't be that difficult, pretty much every site out there right now has every element of what I need all together in one place but there isn't a simple starting point for someone to learn. All the tutorials I have seen start with one subject matter, and for the next part change tact completely so that there is no consistency/scope to be able to follow along. I would put something together from the very outset, explaining what the tutorial is for, and what technologies/languages we will be using and go from there.

Comment: Detailing each step along the way with fully commented code. Something which a lot of people lack these days. Are you able to shed any light on getting this done?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have a couple of questions wrapped into one large question but I'll try to answer them as best as I can. I'll answer them in the order of importance.

1. How do you update your class(es).
2. How to structure forms better.
3. How to check login status.

1. Most applications now use some form of an MVC architecture. Models, Views, and Controllers are a way of separating responsibilities to classes. Here's a brief [tutorial](http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/) on MVC architecture for PHP. With that said, there are a number of open source frameworks that you can use like, [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/), [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) and more.

   Try using one of the strategies for MVC or try a framework.
2. Try not to have the form self submit to itself. Instead route it to a seperate page and handle the logic there. Also you can wrap your inputs into and array by using the `[]` notation. For example: `<input type="text" name="user[firstname]" />`

   However If you are just doing a login form, then all you need is some unique form of identification and a credential (e.g. username and password).
3. There are several ways to persist users' login status, chiefly used are sessions and cookies. Storing the entire model in the session or cookie is usually frowned upon. Instead try storing the username and a unique key that you can compare against in a database.
   Using cookies gives you more control over how long you want the session to last.